# html label don't work in ajax

Tags: html, ajax, label

I'm loading html page via Ajax.
Here's the data:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dis_net" id="dis_net" value="1" />
<label for="dis_net">Test</label>
```

But the Label does not work. There is a way to solution.
When I click in the Label checkbox to not put a tick

If we write the other way, it works

```
<label for="dis_net">Test</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="dis_net" id="dis_net" value="1" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? .... It might be though that the closing `/>` is the problem, you should be able to drop that

Comment: When I click in the Label checkbox to not put a tick

Comment: @Pekka there is nothing wrong with this `/>`

Comment: you need to put the check box *inside* the label for that to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other way of labeling:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="myinput" />Test</label>
```

This way it alway works. I tested your HTML it worked me well, even by loading it with AJAX. What browser do you test it? Strange errors like this can be browser specific.